# What is 'system card'?

Tags: definitions, open-ai, chatgpt, explainable-ai

What is 'system card' in these context:

[image]

https://ai.meta.com/blog/system-cards-a-new-resource-for-understanding-how-ai-systems-work/

> Additionally, individual model developers may provide documentation
> such as the OpenAI **system card** for the GPT-4 model.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/responsible-generative-ai/3-identify-harms

By the way, what is 'model cards'?